# Wicket auth-role : inject external user credential from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, wicket

I am doing an incremental JSP --> Wicket migration. I had kept the JSP appliation and doing page by page migration. I gan go and return from JSP <--> wicket pages.But my problem is in JSP my logged in user credentials are stored in a Bean (UserBean,scope:session) and in JSP on each page I check logged in user from that bean.

But how can I get these informations in wicket? so that from my JSP page if a User is logged in, on wicket page load it can read that and set suer info so that my wicket log in page does not come.

my wicket page uses wicket-auth-role and checks with:

```
@AuthorizeInstantiation("ADMIN") public class HomePage extends BasePage {.....}
```

I have my own UserDetailsServcice and MyAuthenticationWebSession in wicket.

After some attempts and help from Don Roby, here I got userID from session in wicket:

```
        final RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();
        WebRequest wr=(WebRequest)requestCycle.getRequest();
        HttpServletRequest hsr= wr.getHttpServletRequest();

        AuthenticatedWebSession session = OrbitWebSession.get();
        String username = (String)hsr.getSession().getAttribute("SessionUser");
```

Now,exactly where can I set username,password and call authenticate so that my page does not redirects to login page? Who calls authenticate() methods and how? I have tried onBeforeRender() method on my secured page,but it does not work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More code specifically around the login process might help us make a more complete answer, but basically you have to get access to the normal servlet container session and thus to that bean from somewhere in wicket.  Likely the best place to put that logic is somewhere in your `MyAuthenticationWebSession`, so that it knows the user is logged in.

To get at the servlet container session from wicket code, you can use

```
httpSession =
((WebRequest)request).getHttpServletRequest().getSession();
```

If at the point you're putting this in your wicket code you don't already have this `WebRequest` object (which is likely a `ServletWebRequest` object), you can get it from the `RequestCycle`:

```
RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();
Request request = requestCycle.getRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

authenticate is called by AuthenticatedWebSession during the login process. Unfortunately for you, most methods in the aforementioned class are marked final so it's a bit hard to customize.

What I think you should be able to do is to use the protected method signIn(boolean value) in the constructor of your own session. You get a Request there, from that you should hopefully be able to get your "SessionUser", then extract your User via your UserDetailsService, call signIn(true) and initialize the correct roles for that user. If signIn(true) is called, you shouldn't get a redirect to login.